# Example of non polynomial differentiable function on $R$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, polynomials

$f(x)=a_{0}+a_{1}x+ a_{2}x^{2}\cdots+ a_{n}x^{n}+ \cdots $ is called a polynomial function.Domain of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{R}$.
We know that all polynomial functions are differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$.
But some examples of non differentiable functions are $|x|$, signum function,floor function and ceiling function.

Can we say that all non differentiable functions are the functions which do not have a polynomial expansion ?

I tried to prove my argument in this way :If $f(x)$ is polynomial function then $f(x) $ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Contrapositive of this statement is if $f(x)$  is not differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ then $f(x)$ is not a polynomial function.

But I am not convinced with this argument. Can any one  give a more stronger proof or give a counter example (That means a differentiable function which does not have a polynomial expansion.) ?

Comment: Did you confuse analytical and polynomial functions? Take $f(x)=x·|x|$ as a differentiable function that is not "polynomial".

Comment: How about $\log x$? It may be expressed as a sum of terms of $x$, with a restriction of $x$. Does that work?

Comment: Your logic that if $f$ is a polynomial than it is differentiable is correct, as is the contrapositive, i.e. that if $f$ is not differentiable, then $f$ is not polynomial. However, this does _not_ imply that if $f$ is not polynomial, then $f$ is not differentiable (and therefore does not imply that if $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is polynomial).

Answer (score 4):

First, note that a polynomial, by definition, has finite number of terms: $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+\dots+a_n x^n$.

What you proved is actually true: a non-differentiable function cannot be a polynomial. However, this does **not** tell that a differentiable function is a polynomial.

There do exist functions which are differentiable, but are not polynomials.

Consider this examples:

- A differentiable piecewise-polynomial function - strictly speaking, it is not a bare polynomial.
- Any famous analytic function, like $e^x$ or $\sin x$, is differentiable, but not polynomial. These are, however, *almost* polynomial: they posess a Taylor expansion and coincide with it.
- $e^{-{1 \over x^2}}$ is even worse: it is smooth (hence also differentiable), but not even analytic.